# some confusion of limsup and its connection with limit points and subsequential limits

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Edited after Jjagmath comment:

I am trying to understand why can we always construct a subsequence that will converge to the limsup.

Rudin defines the $\limsup$ as the supremum of the set of subsequential limits.

I've seen the $\limsup$ also referred to as the supremum of the set of limit points ( proof attempt below)

**This seems to suggest that every limit point is a subsequential limit but the converse is false e.g. take $(-1)^{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, Then -1 is a subsequential limit but not a limit point?** So does that mean the set of limit points is a subset of subsequential limits?

**Attempt at trying to show limsup is sup of limit points:**

Let $x_{n}$ be a bounded sequence and $b_{n}:= \sup\{a_{k}: k \geq \}$ then by definition $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n} = \limsup_{n \to \infty}a_{n}$. Now since $(b_{n})$ converges every subsequence converges to the same limit. So let $(a_{n_{k}})$ be a convergent subsequence. Then $a_{n_{k}} \leq b_{n_{k}} \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. If I then take limits I get $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_{n_{k}} \leq \lim_{k \to \infty}b_{n_{k}} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_{n}$

I am not sure how to then proceed...

**Attempt at trying to show we can construct a subsequence that will converge to limsup:**

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence of real numbers and $\alpha = \limsup x_{n}$
If I assume that limsup is the supremum of all limitpoints then there is some $x_{n_{1}}$ (say) such that $|x_{n_{1}} - \alpha| < \frac{1}{2}$. Similarly for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, some $k_{n_{k}}$ such that $|x_{n_{k}} - \alpha| < \frac{1}{2^{k}}$. Result follows.

Comment: "Rudin defines the $\lim \sup(x_n)$ as the set of subsequential limits." I doubt that, the $\lim\sup$ is not a set. Is the supremum of certain set.

Comment: Are you aware the there are two different concepts called "limit point"? The limit point of a set and the limit point of a sequence.

Comment: @jjagmath What I wrote is for a sequence $x_{n}$ poor notation on my part. but no I wasn't ware that there are two different types of limit point.

Comment: The definition you cited is for the notion of the limit point of a set. You probably want to edit your question.

Comment: @jjagmath I have edited the question, as per your suggestion, is it okay now?